# pseudocode understanding Mauch lesson

Tags: python-3.x, pseudocode

```
display user message
WHILE TRUE
get score
if score is from 0 to 100
add score to score total
add 1 to number of scores
elseif score i 999
end loop
else print error message
calculate average score
display results
```

------------------------------------ I wrote it like this----------

```
#welcome message
print("thank us for testing")
print ("enter 999 to top running")
print ("*"* 20)

while True:
    score = int(input("Enter grad score: "))
    scores = 0 

    if score >=0 and score <=100:
        score += scoreTotal
        scores += 1

    elif score == 999:
        break
    else:
        print("error message")
averageScore = scoreTotal / score.
```

---

### i'm tryin to learn with this Mauch book, though it's a bit confusing once i got to pseudocode. Can someone explain what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing crucial tabs after your loops and if statments

Comment: Please double-check your indentation here.  As-is this is not a syntactically valid python program because of the (lack of) indentation.

Comment: I fixed the indentation , i had it indented correctly on the RPi system though when i typed it here i forgot to put the tabs.

Comment: it is still indented incorrectly on your else cases and you have a colon missing on the if. In addition, you have undefined variables

Comment: Should be gold now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have some simple syntactic issues in the order you are adding things,etc. Keeping scores in the loop resets it to 0 every time you loop, which I assume is not what you want. Also, make sure you check the division by zero at the end of the loop. All can be seen below:

```
#welcome message
print("thank us for testing")
print ("enter 999 to top running")
print ("*"* 20)

scoreTotal = 0
scores = 0 #moved out of the loop to maintain value

while True:
    score = int(input("Enter grad score: ")) 

    if score >=0 and score <=100:
        scoreTotal += score #equivalent to scoreTotal = scoreTotal + score
        scores += 1

    elif score == 999:
        break
    else:
        print("error message")
#check for division by zero error
if scores > 0:
    averageScore = scoreTotal / scores
else:
    averageScore = 0
```